# List perfomance vs ArrayList memory allocation performance

Tags: c#, .net, list, arraylist

I have following code:

```
namespace ConsoleCodeGenerator
{
    internal class Foo
    {
        public double F { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int size = 100000;
            int size = 70000000;

            List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>(size);
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(size);

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Foo f = new Foo();
                f.F = i;
                list.Add(f);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("List: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw2.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Foo f = new Foo();
                f.F = i;
                arrayList.Add(f);
            }
            sw2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("arrayList: {0}", sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

if I use int size = 100000; then List outperfoms ArrayList with proportion 2:6 miliseconds. But if to make size = 70000000; Then ArrayList has better perfomance 5450:4809 at my computer. It looks like for processing huge ( around millions of items) ArrayList may be faster then List. Why boxing/unboxing matters at small memory allocation, and doesn't matter at big arrays

Comment: Your question is ...?

Comment: Why boxing/unboxing matters at small memory allocation, and doesn't matter at big arrays

Comment: Are you compiling in Release mode and running the app without the debugger?

Comment: With a size of 100K and a measurement time of *milliseconds*, your results aren't going to be terribly stable. Additionally, you're not JITting the code before you start, and you're not clearing garbage between tests.

Comment: Also, note that there's no boxing/unboxing going on, since you're not storing value types.

Comment: Do you actually need 70.000.000 elements in a list? You can check the similarity between both lists on http://referencesource.microsoft.com. As you can see they should perform the same.

Comment: This question was born during testing and searching for better performance bottlenecks

Comment: @Areius They perform roughly the same for reference types. For value types, the difference is very much there. Of course, it's never clear-cut - if you're inserting large structs, expanding an `ArrayList` will be much cheaper than expanding a `List`.

Comment: `List<>` use an `ArrayList` in the background so performance should be nearly the same. With `List<>` there should have a handful of extra instructions to interpret but not visible to the naked eye

Comment: No, it isn't using an ArrayList, it uses an array. Check the referencesource I mentioned earlier. The same for ArrayList by the way, it also uses an array.

Comment: @Areius My source reference shows array list `protected ArrayList InnerList { get { if (list == null) list = new ArrayList(); return list; } }`

Comment: That's the CollectionBase, but ArrayList and List don't use it Franck. Check here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs and here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is a bit deeper than that.

For one, making a good benchmark is hard - yours isn't good.

Second, boxing only occurs on *value types* - you're adding a class in both cases, so no boxing occurs even with `ArrayList`. In fact, by wrapping the `double` in a class, you've just manually *boxed* the value - that's what boxing means (of course, the IL `box` / `unbox` instructions are probably a bit more efficient). Try inserting the `double` directly, and you'll see the massive difference.

To expand a bit on the benchmark issues, you're completely ignoring memory allocation (and collection) patterns. While you're preallocating the arrays themselves (that's what the capacity argument is for), you're not preallocating the objects (`Foo`). This wouldn't be important with structs or `double`s, for example, but in this case, you're simply pushing all the memory pressure into the relevant cycles.

The `List` is elligible for collection as soon as it's no longer used in the method, so the `ArrayList` will get a free, pre-prepared memory as soon as it needs a collection. So even the order of the tests will make a small difference.

Finally, you want repeatability - make a hundred tests with `List`, another hundred with `ArrayList`, in as much of an isolation as possible. And don't forget to pre-heat the benchmark to get rid of initialization times.

You can find a lot of information on making a decent benchmark in C#. It really isn't easy.

Comment: Yes, if to change to double then difference between List and ArrayList is 486: 5107. Thanks